# Why can't I read these properties using """ ${ array[a].name} """?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Why can't I read the properties using `${ array[a].name }` with For of ?
I made an ex with an array of objects just to simplify the problem diagnosis

```js
const movie = [{
    name: "Shrek",
    year: 2001
  },
  {
    name: "Shrek 2",
    year: 2004
  },
  {
    name: "Shrek Third",
    year: 2007
  },
  {
    name: "Shrek For Ever",
    year: 2010
  }
]

forIn = array => {
  for (a in array) {
    console.log(`Index ${a} in Array Object`)
    console.log(`FOR IN array[a] -> ${array[a]}`, array[a])
    console.log(`FOR IN array[a].nome -> ${array[a].nome}`)
    console.log(`FOR IN array[a].year -> ${array[a].year}`)
    console.log('')
  }
}

forOf = array => {
  for (a of array) {
    console.log(`Index of Array -> Object`)
    console.log(a)
    console.log(array[a])
    console.log('')
    /*      console.log(`FOR OF array[a].name -> ${array[a].name}`)  ERROR LINE */
  }
}
forIn(movie)
console.log('')
forOf(movie)
```

Comment: That's the whole difference between `for in` and `for of`. Why would you expect to be able to use them the same way?

Comment: nome != name...

Comment: You should read about [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) on MDN and see what it says. Documentation will tell you what is different and why it does not work.

Comment: The `for a of array` loop does not give you the index. So `array[a]` makes no sense in that construct. Read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 0):

with for of loop a is already the value, it is not the index so use a.name inside the loop

```js
const movies = [  { name: "Shrek", year: 2001 },
        { name: "Shrek 2", year: 2004 },
        { name: "Shrek Third", year: 2007 },
        { name: "Shrek For Ever", year: 2010 }
    ]
   
        for (m of movies) {            
            console.log(m)
            console.log(m.name)
            console.log(m.year)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First iteration 'of' loop:

- in variable 'a' you have first object from array: `{ name: 'Shrek', year: 2001 }`
- array[a] is undefined - you cannot access element of array that way
- you call array[a].name ---> undefined.name ---> error: you cannot access property 'name' of undefined